# Why is there a delay between requests on a thread in THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am running batch requests (50+) simultaneously and I execute them In a loop like so

```
for(AsyncTask task : myTasks){
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
}
```

That was when I checked my network profiler and saw that it looked like this:

[image: Network Profile]

Why is there this delay (marked in red) between requests when adding new Tasks from the queue to the `Thread`?

Comment: As you are using a pool of threads, there must be delays if you try to execute more than the pool can handle.

Comment: @aran Yes, but why is the delay from taking a task from the queue to running it on a thread that has finished it's previous task so huge (in the order of seconds) The task time was roughly 1.5s, but the delay seems to be much more (at least 4+ seconds)

Comment: 4 seconds seems a lot for the delay parameter of the threadpool (don't remember the actual name). Seems strange..

Comment: Perhaps your `AsyncTask` implementation is consuming that time. Also, I strongly recommend using something more modern than `AsyncTask`: `LiveData`, Kotlin coroutines, or RxJava.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm working on a performance issue on an existing project, and I have to use the existing `AsyncTask` Implementation (Changing that would require some major overhaul). 

I did check the entire `doInBackground()` Time of my `AsyncTask`, and it is about 200ms more than network call time, So that shouldn't be the cause of this delay

Comment: Perhaps some other tasks elsewhere in the app are consuming threads. You might try replacing `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` with your own private `Executor` and see if you get a change in behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did try that as well. The same issue exists. Is it perhaps something related to time slicing of the thread?

Comment: If possible, you might try using your private `Executor` directly, doing the network I/O and related processing. If that clears up the problem, then the delays are somewhere inside of `AsyncTask` itself, perhaps tied to how it updates the main application thread. If you see the same problems with the plain `Executor`, though, then I doubt that there is much you can do about it, as the problem is either tied with how you are measuring this, in how the threads get scheduled, etc.